# docker does not preserve state

Tags: docker, jenkins

I made a `docker pull jenkins:latest`

then I ran the container: `docker run --name jenk -p 8080:8080 jenkins`

I set up all the jobs, configurations, etc within jenkins. Afterwards I committed the change:

`docker commit jenk myrepo/jenkins`

when I now pull the image and start it: `docker run myrepo/jenkins` all the configuration is lost. I thought it would preserve it.

Comment: I don't use the jenkins image but I don't see anything wrong with your description. BTW, a best practice is to create named volumes for persistent data and mount them to your container instead of relying on `docker commit`.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to **push** it to your (remote) repository before you can pull it again. The commit only saves the state to your local drive. A pull always goes to a repository.

Some free advice:

- It is mostly advisable to make changes by doing this through a `Dockerfile` though, by extending the jenkins:latest and adding your own changes to it. This makes it much more maintainable and changeable.

Question:

Did you do this all inside the image or also on mounted volumes?
according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#description) those settings will not be included

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container.

Have fun :-)

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [docker commit documentation:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description)

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes
>   mounted inside the container.

The jenkins image declared the jenkins home as a volume `VOLUME /var/jenkins_home`. The volume container all the configuration and jobs created. Thus when you commit the container, all this configuration willnot be persisted in the 
commited image.

If you are running the new image on the same machine, you can use the jenkins_home volume from the older container and get exactly the same jenkins instance:

```
docker volume ls  //To determine the old container volume name
docker run -v <old-volume-name>:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 myrepo/jenkins
```

If you are running the commited intance on a new machine:

```
docker cp <old-container>:/var/jenkins_home ./jenkins_home
```

Now copy the jenkins_home folder onto the new machine, and mount it onto the new container:

```
docker run -v ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 myrepo/jenkins
```